# Reactor Netty - Change of behavior in connection pool metrics

Tags: spring-boot, connection-pooling, metrics, reactor-netty

When I switch to Reactor-Netty 0.9.5.RELEASE (Spring Boot 2.5.RELEASE), connection pool metrics aggregation change.

I use a named connection pool, as for example:

```java
ConnectionProvider.create("a_name", 100);
```

When I look at metrics, it seems I get a Gauge per opened connection:

```
reactor_netty_connection_provider_a_name_total_connections{id="211417729",remote_address="remote.host:443",} 1.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_a_name_total_connections{id="211417729",remote_address="remote.host:443",} 1.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_a_name_total_connections{id="211417729",remote_address="remote.host:443",} 1.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_a_name_total_connections{id="211417729",remote_address="remote.host:443",} 1.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_a_name_total_connections{id="-928004310",remote_address="remote.host:443",} 1.0
reactor_netty_connection_provider_a_name_total_connections{id="1727380098",remote_address="remote.host:443",} 1.0
...
```

*NB: I use Apache ab to perform so light tests with concurrency*

That makes the metrics unusable cause I have no mean to know what the actual pool total size is.
If I go back to prior versions, using something like:

```java
ConnectionProvider.fixed("a_name", 100);
```

I always get one Gauge with - I assume - accurate total connections.

To bring the full picture, I'd like to have the ratio between configured max pool size and actual pool size (connections acquired in pool, no matter their state).

Am I misusing or misunderstanding something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think this is a regression, please create an issue with a reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: Done here: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/1041

Comment: A workaround provided by @VioletaGeorgieva on the github issue is to enable the metrics not at the tcp client configuration level, but a the connection provider one.